# Can't Added Service Reference from WFC

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf

(In VS 2010)
I can't add a service reference to a WCF service in a Windows Forms Project. When I go to add a service reference I click the "Discover" button. It brings up the service I want to add (within the same solution). I click the "OK" button. A server port starts (according to a popup dialog). And I get a Meassage box that pops up and says "There was an error downloading metadata from the address. Please verify that you have entered a valid address." Rats! I don't know what to do :( Now I did mess around with the WCF service project's Web.Config file before I tried to do this. I don't know if that would affect anything. Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: Unmess arounf. Seriously.

Comment: The Web.config file may contain details about the endpoints for your WCF service. If this is incorrect, you may receive an error like that.. it's impossible to help without the code in this case..

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="enterpriseLibrary.ConfigurationSource" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ConfigurationSourceSection, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=763b11457dd635bc"/>
  </configSections>

Comment: <enterpriseLibrary.ConfigurationSource selectedSource="BaseDataAccess">
    <sources>
      <add name="BaseDataAccess" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.FileConfigurationSource, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=763b11457dd635bc" filePath="C:\Entlib\EntLib50.config"/>
    </sources>
  </enterpriseLibrary.ConfigurationSource>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>

Comment: <services>
      <service name="WcfFormsAttachment.FormsAttachment" behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehaviorLargeObject">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpServiceBinding_LargeMessageMtom" contract="WcfFormsAttachment.IFormsAttachment"/>
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="netTcpServiceBindingLargeMessage" contract="WcfFormsAttachment.IFormsAttachment" />

Comment: </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
  
</configuration>

Comment: Henk Holterman, I would appreciate helpful, not snarky, comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered an answer to my own question. Apparently you can get this error if you rename your service but don't change the service name in your .svc file.